# Highlight all instances of same link when any are hover over

Tags: html, css

Say I have several links in a page, many (but not all) point to the same resource.  They might not all have identical stylings (one might be an image, one just text) and they may be interspersed throughout the page. I want for if someone hovers over one, they all highlight (eg `:hover`).

For example:

```css
a img{border:3px solid blue;}
a img:hover{border:3px solid orange;}
a:hover{color:orange;}
```

```html
<a href="" class="multilink"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/8be0d3/a30fbd.png&text=Awesome" alt="placeholder"></a>
<p>My <a href="" class="multilink">awesome website</a> has recently been updated. You should visit my <a href="" class="multilink">sweet webpage</a>. If  you are on mobile, I've include image links so your big fat fingers can click them easier.
```

I'm not completely opposed to using jquery, but if there's a way to do it with *just* CSS that would be ideal.

Comment: you can use the class name `multilink`

Comment: This is not going to be possible with CSS alone. While you can target the 2nd & 3rd links in your example when hovering the first, you *cannot* target the 1st when hovering the 2nd or 3rd, nor the 2nd when hovering the 3rd.

Comment: @Shaggy can't he combine nth-child?

Comment: Combine it with what @DaniSpringer? `:nth-child()` won't solve the problem that there is no way to select a parent element or previous sibling element in CSS.

Comment: Apply nth to parent of links.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with css only
Try this code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<style>
a img{border:3px solid blue;}
a img:hover{border:3px solid orange;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="" class="multilink"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/8be0d3/a30fbd.png&text=Awesome" alt="placeholder"></a>
<p>My <a href="" class="multilink">awesome website</a> has recently been updated. You should visit my <a href="" class="multilink">sweet webpage</a>. If  you are on mobile, I've include image links so your big fat fingers can click them easier.
<script>
$("a").hover(function() {
$("a").css({color:"orange"});
},function() {
$("a").css({color:"black"});
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this -

```css
span.some-class:hover > a.multilink { background:black };
a img{border:3px solid blue;}
a img:hover{border:3px solid orange;}
a:hover{color:orange;}
```

```html
<p><span class="some-class"><a href="" class="multilink"><img src="http://dummyimage.com/200x100/8be0d3/a30fbd.png&text=Awesome" alt="placeholder"></a></span></p>
<p>My <span class="some-class"><a href="" class="multilink">awesome website</a></span> has recently been updated. You should visit my <span class="some-class"><a href="" class="multilink">sweet webpage</a></span>. If  you are on mobile, I've include image links so your big fat fingers can click them easier.</p>
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: You could lose the class on the span or the anchor, depending on which you'd prefer.

Comment: Unfortunately, that only seems to affect one link at a time.